# API JSON javascript extract data loop array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, extract

I've succeeded at connecting and getting JSON data from API using this method:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   fetch('https://api.web_address.com/vi/locations/10', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer my_bearer_token'
    },
})
.then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json()

    } else {
      return Promise.reject({
        status: response.status,
        statusText: response.statusText
      })
    }
  })
.then(data => console.log('data is', data))
.catch(error => {
    if (error.status === 404) {
      // do something about 404
    }
  })
</script>
```

The API gives this data:

```
{
    "message": "OK",
    "data": {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "First floor",
        "count": 96,
        "percentage": 0.06,
        "timestamp": "2023-02-25T03:53:25.279Z",
        "isActive": true,
        "childCounts": [
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Room 101",
                "count": 36,
                "percentage": 0.1,
                "isActive": true
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "name": "Room 102",
                "count": 17,
                "percentage": 0.06,
                "isActive": true
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "name": "Room 103",
                "count": 12,
                "percentage": 0.04,
                "isActive": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I loop to get the "name" and "percentage"? And where do I put the loop?
Hope the description is clear to you because I've tried and tried and can't get anything working...Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   fetch('https://api.web_address.com/vi/locations/10', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer my_bearer_token'
    },
})
.then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json()

    } else {
      return Promise.reject({
        status: response.status,
        statusText: response.statusText
      })
    }
  })
.then(rawData => { // Add another 'then' block here
    const {data: {childCounts = []} = {}} = rawData; //default values when destructuring
    return childCounts.map(({name = '', count = 0}) => ({ // always good to have defaults
        name,
        count
    }))
})
.then(data => console.log('data is', data)) // Now this data is the data you want
.catch(error => {
    if (error.status === 404) {
      // do something about 404
    }
  })
</script>
```

Note: Try and use async/await if you are dealing with promises.

Comment: Thans it worked very well. I now get this:

Comment: Thanks it worked very well. I now get this:
Array(5)0: {name: 'Room 101', percentage: 0.21}1: {name: 'Room 102', percentage: 0.08}2: {name: 'Room 103', percentage: 0.15}3: {name: 'Room 104', percentage: 0.12}name: "Room 105"percentage: 0.12[[Prototype]]: Object4: {name: 'Room 106', percentage: 0.08}

So now, this is an array. and I can just loop the array to display the content on a page?

Comment: If this is the data you need, then looping over it would work. How you loop over it would depend on the framework/library you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over `.data.childCounts`.

```js
let o = { "message": "OK", "data": { "id": 10, "name": "First floor", "count": 96, "percentage": 0.06, "timestamp": "2023-02-25T03:53:25.279Z", "isActive": true, "childCounts": [ { "id": 11, "name": "Room 101", "count": 36, "percentage": 0.1, "isActive": true }, { "id": 12, "name": "Room 102", "count": 17, "percentage": 0.06, "isActive": true }, { "id": 13, "name": "Room 103", "count": 12, "percentage": 0.04, "isActive": true } ] } };
for (const {name, percentage} of o.data.childCounts) {
  console.log(name, percentage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how do you get the "return response.json()" into a variable?

Comment: @w2012z You can only access it in the next `.then` callback.

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:

```
let o = { "message": "OK", "data": { "id": 10, "name": "First floor", "count": 96, "percentage": 0.06, "timestamp": "2023-02-25T03:53:25.279Z", "isActive": true, "childCounts": [ { "id": 11, "name": "Room 101", "count": 36, "percentage": 0.1, "isActive": true }, { "id": 12, "name": "Room 102", "count": 17, "percentage": 0.06, "isActive": true }, { "id": 13, "name": "Room 103", "count": 12, "percentage": 0.04, "isActive": true } ] } };

o.data.childCounts.map((ele)=> {
  const {name, percentage} = ele;
  console.log(name, percentage)
})
```

Hope it would be help to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` method with `object destructuring` syntax :

```js
const data = {"message":"OK","data":{"id":10,"name":"First floor","count":96,"percentage":0.06,"timestamp":"2023-02-25T03:53:25.279Z","isActive":true,"childCounts":[{"id":11,"name":"Room 101","count":36,"percentage":0.1,"isActive":true},{"id":12,"name":"Room 102","count":17,"percentage":0.06,"isActive":true},{"id":13,"name":"Room 103","count":12,"percentage":0.04,"isActive":true}]}};

const processData = (data) => {
  const { childCounts } = data.data || {};
  return childCounts ? childCounts.map(({ name, percentage }) => ({ name, percentage })) : [];
a;
}

console.log(processData(data));
console.log(processData({})); // []
```